# Pandas passing arguments to apply

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function to a dataframe, creating a new column as a result, like so:

```
def defensive_weights(DSp=None,SGp=None,FCp=None):
    if dfcrop['opp_goals'] == 0:
        DInd = (DSp*2 + SGp + FCp)
    else:
        DInd = (DSp + SGp + FCp)

    return DInd
   
dfcrop['IED'] = dfcrop['opp_goals'].apply(defensive_weights, DSp=DSp,SGp=SGp,FCp=FCp)
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: defensive_weights() got multiple values for argument 'DSp'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The first argument of the function should be the series you are passing to it. So in your case add an argument `x` (or some better name) and replace `dfcrop['opp_goals']` with `x` inside the function call.

Comment: could you please answer to make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're calling the entire dataframe series from within the function. I don't think you want to do this. You should allow the function to take a parameter, and pass it to the conditional:

```
def defensive_weights(item, DSp=None,SGp=None,FCp=None):
    if item == 0:
        DInd = (DSp*2 + SGp + FCp)
    else:
        DInd = (DSp + SGp + FCp)

    return DInd
```

Let's say dfcrop['opp_goals'] == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Right now, your function is trying to do this:

```
if [1,2,3,4,5] == 0:
```

It would always return false in this case.

It's passing the entire column for each row, because you're calling it from within the function.

I have a feeling you want it to do this:

```
if 2 == 0
```

or

```
if 0 == 0
```

So you need to provide the function with just those integers. You do this by feeding them in one by one, which is not really easily done from within the function, you need to create a function parameter (I called it "item"), and feed them in one by one using your "apply" method.

Also, your apply syntax is calling the entire row and attempting to pass it to the first parameter. I'd recommend using a lambda to control which columns go to which parameters:

```
dfcrop.apply(lambda x: defensive_weights(x.opp_goals, DSp=x.DSp,SGp=x.SGp,FCp=x.FCp), axis=1)
```

I don't know what your data looks like so I am assuming you have several columns named after those named parameters.

Edit: Here's a simple example of a function passed to the apply method that should illustrate the nuts and bolts of how to use apply:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,6,7,8]})

def modder(x,y):
    return x**y

a['c'] = a.apply(lambda x: modder(x.a, x.b), axis=1)
a
```

Comment: AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'opp_goals'", 'occurred at index nome')

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like so if you can provide a few rows it'd be helpful. Also, I forgot the "axis" argument. Modified my answer a bit.